# How to filter emails based on received date using microsoft graph api with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api, filtering, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm working on a python script to retrieve emails based on receiveddatetime. When i run my script i get the error below.

[image]

Below is my whole script.

```
import msal
import json
import requests

def get_access_token():
    tenantID = 'yyy'
    authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenantID
    clientID = 'xxx'
    clientSecret = 'xxx'
    scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(clientID, authority=authority, client_credential = clientSecret)
    access_token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
    return access_token

# token block
access_token = get_access_token()
token = access_token['access_token']


# Set the parameters for the email search
# received 2023-01-22T21:13:24Z
date_received = '2023-01-22T21:13:24Z'
mail_subject = 'Test Mail'
mail_sender = 'bernardberbell@gmail.com'
mailuser = 'bernardmwanza@bernardcomms.onmicrosoft.com'

# Construct the URL for the Microsoft Graph API
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{}/Messages?$filter=(ReceivedDateTime ge '{}')&$select=subject,from".format(mailuser, date_received)

# Set the headers for the API call
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Send the API request and get the response
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response)

# Parse the response as JSON
data = json.loads(response.text)

print(data)
```

I tried to modify the api call like below, but still i get the same error. What am i doing wrong here?

```
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{}/Messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge '{}'&$select=subject,from".format(mailuser, date_received)
```

Comment: as the error suggests the issue is with the filter. Could you try extracting out the whole filter's value and then simply replace it in the url?
**filter=f'ReceivedDateTime ge {mailuser}'**

and then in the url **$filter={filter}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use single quotes when you want to filter messages by `ReceivedDateTime`  in `$filter=(ReceivedDateTime ge '{}')`. Also parenthesis are not mandatory.

This should work:

```
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{}/Messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge {}&$select=subject,from".format(mailuser, date_received)
```